# How to send message to specific user in signalr using group?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am new to asp.net core and I am trying to develop a chat application using signalR.
I am using asp.net core mvc, Based on my previous research, i have managed to implement the chatting but the problem is all of them can receive the message, I did tried using client.group which is it worked, i can now send message to specific group. I want to send and receive message from specific person using client.group instead of client.user, is it possible?
I have this code in my hub.

```
public Task SendMessageToGroup(string groupName, string message)
{
return Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId}: {message}");
}

public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}

public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName)
{
await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");
}
```

and in my client side

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/chatHub")
.build();
connection.on("Send", function (message) {
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.textContent = message;
document.getElementById("messagesList").appendChild(li);
});
document.getElementById("groupmsg").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
var groupName = document.getElementById("group-name").value;
var groupMsg = document.getElementById("group-message-text").value;
try {
await connection.invoke("SendMessageToGroup", groupName, groupMsg);
}
catch (e) {
console.error(e.toString());
}
event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("join-group").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
var groupName = document.getElementById("group-name").value;
try {
await connection.invoke("AddToGroup", groupName);
}
catch (e) {
console.error(e.toString());
}
event.preventDefault();
});
document.getElementById("leave-group").addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
var groupName = document.getElementById("group-name").value;
try {
await connection.invoke("RemoveFromGroup", groupName);
}
catch (e) {
console.error(e.toString());
}
event.preventDefault();
});
// We need an async function in order to use await, but we want this code to run immediately,
// so we use an "immediately-executed async function"
(async () => {
try {
await connection.start();
}
catch (e) {
console.error(e.toString());
}
})();
```

and finally here is my view

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-6">
<form class="form-inline">
<div class="input-prepend input-append">
<input type="text" name="group-message" id="group-message-text" placeholder="Type a message" />
<input type="text" name="group-name" id="group-name" placeholder="Type a group name" />
<input type="button" id="groupmsg" class="btn" value="Send to Group" />
<input type="button" id="join-group" class="btn" value="Join Group" />
<input type="button" id="leave-group" class="btn" value="Leave Group" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-12">
<hr />
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-6">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col-6">
<ul id="messagesList"></ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="~/js/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/chat.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to send and receive message from specific person using client.group instead of client.user, is it possible?

Yes, you can acheive it by using single-user group.

1) create a group for each user, and name the group with user name

2) then send a message to that group when you want to reach only that user, like below.

```
Clients.Group(who).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId}: {message}")
```

Comment: In [ASP.NET SignalR document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections#single-user-groups), you can find details about **single-user groups**, and you can achieve same in ASP.NET Core SignalR.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response @Fei Han, What about in my client side? what should I do?

Comment: 1) For joining single-user group, on client side, you could invoke hub method `AddToGroup` and pass name of current user as group name; 2) For sending message to a specific user via single-user group, you just need to pass name of that single-user group (receiver name) and message to you hub method, then use code snippet in my post to send it.

Comment: Single-user group(s) is same as general SignalR group, you can implement functionality via single-user group as you did with other general groups.

Comment: Hi @RichardVillasencio, if you have any question about using single-user groups, please let me know. Besides, if the solution is helpful, you can vote or [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).