# SignalR how to send a message only to specific user/group with typescript client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

I have signalr net core server, currently sending messages to all clients. I've added additional method in publisher, but these messages have to be sent only to specific users.

Currently on client side this is the react typescript implementation(connection):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const newConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(props.dataWssUrl, {
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    setConnection(newConnection);
  }, []);
```

and listening to messages that should be delivered to all clients:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      if (connection) {
        try {
          await connection.start();
          console.log("Connected");

          connection.on("UserIsOnline", (walletAddress) => {
            const hiddenAddress = "(" + walletAddress.substring(0, 4) + ")";

            toast(
              "User just joined: " + hiddenAddress,
              {
                position: "bottom-right",
                autoClose: 2000,
                hideProgressBar: true,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: false,
                progress: undefined,
                transition: Flip,
              }
            );
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Connection failed: " + error);
        }
      }
    })();
  }, [connection]);
```

Now I have another message, which should be delivered to only specific user/group, not all clients.

Now in order for me to map signalR connectionId and userId, I googled if I can somehow send the clientId from client side when I create a new hub connection, but results were that headers cannot be sent via websockets in this case.

What are my options? Can I make a `HubMethod` on server side, and then `subscribe` to it via client by passing parameter, and add group that way? I've tried something with `connection.Invoke('HubMethod', 'stringArgument'), but debug did not hit my try of subscription. Does anyone have some working example of how could I map a userId with ConnectionId with React Typescript client and net core as server, so I could then distribute the message only to specific user?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60715278/how-to-send-message-to-specific-user-in-signalr-using-group) may be helpful.

Comment: i tried like that but when i try to invoke method from typescript client, it doesn't hit debug. i will tray again.

Answer (score 1):

with .net authentication in place you can use the Identity in signalR hub to get the user for each specific connection, if you don't have for each user you can use some other strategies.
But as you said you can use groups if it fits your need.
In HUB class you should add method to register a name for the group and register that connection in that group

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
public async Task AddToGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has joined the group {groupName}.");
}

public async Task RemoveFromGroup(string groupName)
{
    await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);

    await Clients.Group(groupName).SendAsync("Send", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has left the group {groupName}.");
}

}
```

From typescript just connect to hub endpoint and send a request to AddToGroup with a string name for the group

```
connection.invoke('AddToGroup', 'myGroup')
```

and you also have to register some function, some handler when messages arrives. be sure to use the same string of the SendAsync in this example "Send".

```
connection.on('Send', myHandlreFunction);
myHandlreFunction = (message : any) => { console.log(message); }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Send Direct Message Methode in the Hub**

```
        public async Task SendDirectMessage(string messages , UserModel targetUserModel)
        {
                      //*** Who is the sender***//;
                    
        var Sender = _userInfoModelInMemory.GetUserInfoModel(Context.User.Identity.Name);
        var Reciever = _userInfoInMemory.GetUserInfo(targetUserModel.UserName);

        var userInfoSender = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Context.User.Identity.Name);
        var userInfoReciever = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(targetUserModel.UserName);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messages.Trim()))
            {
                //*** Build the message model *** //
                var messageModel = new MessageViewModel()
                {
                    //******//
                };
            // Send the message && Test if the user is offline :
            //Find My opened sessions and target opened sessions

            if (userInfoReciever != null)
            {
                var targetSessions = _context.Connections.Where(C => (C.Username == targetUserModel.UserName) && (C.Connected == true)).Select(CID => CID.ConnectionID).ToList();
            // Send to specific user with all his sessions
                await Clients.Clients(targetSessions).SendAsync("SendDM", messageModel, userInfoSender);

            }

            //Send My message to the the others sessions :

            var mySessions = _context.Connections.Where(C => ((C.ConnectionID!=Context.ConnectionId)&&(C.Username == userInfoSender.UserName)&&(C.Connected == true))).Select(MyCID=>MyCID.ConnectionID).ToList();

            if (mySessions != null)
            {
                await Clients.Clients(mySessions).SendAsync("MyMessage", messageModel, userInfoSender);
            }

            

            // Build the message
            var _message = _mapper.Map<MessageViewModel,Message>(messageModel);

            await _context.Messages.AddAsync(_message);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
           
            }          
    }
```

'''